# Cannot instantiate custom filter in directshow.net

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

This is what i tried instantiating my filter.

**Using guid directly with activator**

```
Guid myfilterGuid = Guid.Parse("067216DE-E6A1-49C9-A016-074624C20FE5");
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(myfilterGuid);
myfitlter = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

This returned a "class not registered" error.

**Class definition**

```
myfitlter = new MyFilter() as IBaseFilter;
```

Where `MyFilter` is:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace YourControlService
{

    [Guid("067216DE-E6A1-49C9-A016-074624C20FE5")]
    public class MyFilter
    {
        public MyFilter()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This returns null.

The class is registered and I can use it in Graphstudionext or c++ code, so I don't know why it wont work in c#. Also i am not sure if i defined the proxy class in the second approach correctly.

**Bonus Question**

Why is this in my code illegal:

```
[Guid("067216DE-E6A1-49C9-A016-074624C20FE5")]
public class MyFilter
{
    public MyFilter(); //Constructor without codeblock; does not compile

}
```

But here it is ok?

```
namespace DirectShowLib
{
    [Guid("E2510970-F137-11CE-8B67-00AA00A3F1A6")]
    public class AviDest
    {
        public AviDest(); //Constructor without codeblock; compiles
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar stuff kept driving me crazy. I would suggest an IT guy solution. Turn it of and on again (visual studio) and unregister and register the filter again. http://youtu.be/nn2FB1P_Mn8?t=9s

Comment: unfortunately this did not work